# What is the difference between hostname-traffic and Access by ISP-Domain?

Tags: google-analytics, hostname

In google analytics, you can filter by ht and ISP-domain. Let's say my isp domain that my ip points to is number.subdomain.domain.com.

Where do I enter domain.com, under Hostname-Traffic or ISP-Domain? Do I need *.domain.com or similar?

[Screenshot about ISP Domain filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFjau.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Exclude/Include only traffic from the ISP domain**: use this filter to exclude/include only traffic **`from`** a specific domain, such as an ISP or company network.

**Exclude/Include only traffic to the hostname**: use this filter to exclude/include only traffic **`to`** a particular hostname (such as sales.example.com or support.example.com).

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en

Comment: The question is what the difference is. The ISP domain is equal to the hostname following your description.

Comment: Ok, I update my answer, now the difference should be clear :)